# Relacionar structs em C

Tags: c

Olá,
tenho que fazer a relação entre structs em um trabalho em C. Tenho uma struct jogador com os campos nome e código e uma struct animal que tem os campos nome e código. Consigo inserir normalmente os jogadores e os animais cada um em sua struct.

```
struct jogador{
   int codigo;
   char nome;
}TJogador;

struct animal{
   int codigo;
   char nome;
}TAnimal;
```

Porém, cada jogador poderá ter vários animais e preciso relacionar essas duas structs fazendo com que quando um jogador tenha um animal que já está inserido na struct animal ele só faça referência a esse animal para quando eu listar os jogadores já liste os animais dele.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Já aprendeu listas? Você pode fazer uma list do tipo *TAnimal e colocar essa lista na sua struct TJogador. Se postar o restante do código fica mais fácil implementar e melhorará a pergunta.
Se não aprendeu listas ainda pode usar um vetor no lugar, se for permitido no seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz com lista encadeada ou com vetor. Exemplo:

```
    struct animal{
       int codigo;
       char nome[200];
    }TAnimal;

    struct jogador{
       int codigo;
       char nome[200];
       // o numero de animais
       int numeroDeAnimais;
       // as referencias aos animais cadastrados.
       TAnimal* animal[200];
    }TJogador;
```

Você deve inicializar o campo `numeroDeAnimais` com o valor `0` e quando adicionar um animal, você deve incrementar o valor do campo `numeroDeAnimais` e adiciona o animal no fim do vetor `animal`.

Comment: Como eu adiciono o animal no jogador? Por exemplo: jogador[0].codigo = 123; jogador[0].nome = 'Fulano'; jogador[0].animal = ????

Comment: Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:
jogador[0].codigo = 0;
jogador[0].nome = "Fulano";
if(jogador[0].numeroDeAnimais<NUMERO_MAXIMO_DE_ANIMAIS)
    jogador[0].animal[jogador[0].numeroDeAnimais++] = &animal[0];
Para isso o animal já deve estar cadastrado.

Comment: Perfeito, vou testar e volto!!!

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Existem algumas possibilidades para relacionais estruturas em C.

Para uma referência mais "forte", crie um vetor de tamanho fixo de animais na estrutura jogador:

```
typedef struct animal {
   int codigo;
   char nome;
} TAnimal;

#define MAX_ANIMAIS 2
typedef struct jogador{
  int codigo;
  char nome;
  TAnimal animais[MAX_ANIMAIS];
} TJogador;
```

Você poderá adicionar animais em cada jogador com:

```
TJogador jogador;
jogador.animais[0].codigo = 1;
jogador.animais[0].nome = 'a';
jogador.animais[1].codigo = 2;
jogador.animais[1].nome = 'b';
// ...
int i;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_ANIMAIS; i++) {
  printf("TAnimal{%d %c}\n", jogador.animais[i].codigo,
          jogador.animais[i].nome);
}
```

Dessa forma, todo jogador possui um número fixo de animais (2 no exemplo) e os dados dos animais serão partes da estrutura jogador.

Vantagens: o código é mais simples e o layout da memória é ideal caso os animais sejam acessados sempre que o jogador é acessado.
Desvantagens: menos flexível, todo jogador tem obrigatoriamente um número fixo de animais. Isso pode ser contornado criando uma instância especial de animal que representa a ausência do animal (por exemplo, com id == -1).

Outra possibilidade de uma relação mais "fraca" é fazer uso de ponteiros. Por exemplo:

```
typedef struct animal {
   int codigo;
   char nome;
} TAnimal;

typedef struct jogador {
  int codigo;
  char nome;
  int num_animais;
  TAnimal* animais;
} TJogador;
```

Os animais podem ser acessados com:

```
TJogador criaJogador(int codigo, char nome, int num_animais) {
  TJogador jogador;
  jogador.codigo = codigo;
  jogador.nome = nome;
  jogador.num_animais = num_animais;
  jogador.animais = (TAnimal*)malloc(sizeof(TAnimal) * num_animais);
  return jogador;
}

TJogador destroiJogador(TJogador* jogador) {
  free((*jogador).animais);
  (*jogador).num_animais = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    TJogador jogador = criaJogador(1, 'a', 2);
    jogador.animais[0].codigo = 1;
    jogador.animais[0].nome = 'a';
    jogador.animais[1].codigo = 2;
    jogador.animais[1].nome = 'b';
    // ...
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < jogador.num_animais; i++) {
       printf("TAnimal{%d %c}\n", jogador.animais[i].codigo,
              jogador.animais[i].nome);
    }
    destroiJogador(&jogador);
}
```

Dessa forma, todo jogador possui um número variável de animais e os dados dos animais serão alocados dinamicamente na memória.

Desvantagens: código mais complexo.
Vantagens: flexibilidade, sendo possível para cada jogador ter um número próprio de animais.

Comment: Sua resposta foi ótima. Mas me ajude a entender. O que eu preciso é por exemplo a lista de animais ta completa. Quando um jogador tem um animal da lista eu tenho que fazer referencia a esse animal na lista de animais e nao adicionar o animal diretamente em jogador, entendeu? Seu exemplo "fraco" se encaixa na minha solução?

Comment: Se você precisa fazer referência aos animais já alocados seria melhor guardar ponteiros para eles. O número de ponteiros pode ser fixo (`TAnimal* animais[MAX_ANIMAIS]`) ou variável (`TAnimal** animais`) conforme os exemplos. A atribuição seria algo do tipo `jogador.animais[i] = &lista_de_animais[j];`.

Comment: Farei um teste e volto!!!